# Deno Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at evaluate ($deno$/repl.ts:54:34) at Object.replLoop ($deno$/repl.ts:156:13)

Tags: deno

I installed Deno using this `choco install deno` command, if I typed deno, I got the version, but if I try to run my index file, I got this error and whatever I typed i got the error like this(refer the image), what went wrong here, thank you

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier   
    at evaluate ($deno$/repl.ts:54:34)        
    at Object.replLoop ($deno$/repl.ts:156:13)
```

[image: error]

> My index file

```
import {Application} from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts';

import {PORT} from './config.js';
import router from '.router.js';

const app=new Application();

app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allwedMethods());

console.log('Server is running. Open http://localhost:${PORT}');

await app.listen({port:PORT});
```

> config.js

```
export const PORT=5000;
```

> router.js

```
import {Router} from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts';

const router=new Router();

router.get('/',({response})=>{
    response.body='Working';
});

export default router;
```

Comment: `router.allwedMethods` should probably be `router.allowedMethods` (missing an 'o')

Comment: I changed it, thank you, but I got error ` The requested module 'https://deno.land/std@0.55.0/http/server.ts' does not provide an export named 'Router'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed version `1.0.3` so that I got the error, After that, I  uploaded to `1.0.0` or `1.0.5`, I never get this warning

To solve this problem,

1. Open the Command prompt to click Run as Administrator, After that
2. Run this Command to `scoop install deno@1.0.0`
3. Run The program again and Chech it.

---

### # Install a specific version of deno:

```
scoop install deno@1.0.0
```

---

### # Switch to v1.0.0

```
scoop reset deno@1.0.0
```

---

### # Switch to the latest version

```
scoop reset deno
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try run the same RPL command with `--ts` flag like:
`deno run --allow-net --ts` and all other flag you use